# radio button and label

Tags: html, css

I'm not that much experienced in HTML and I wanted to use a designed radio Button.
So, I used these codes from a website and modified it a little bit.
The problem now is whenever I write a sentence in the label it is not appearing in the same line.

Do you have any idea why is that happening ?

Here are the codes

```css
html {
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
}

*, *::after, *::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Raleway', Arial, sans-serif;
}

.toggle-button {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  margin: 0 20px;
}
/*tested*/

.toggle-button label {
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: left;
}
/*tested*/

.toggle-button input {
  display: none;
}

.toggle-button__icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: none;
}
/*to let radio button invites clicking*/

.toggle-button__icon:before, .toggle-button__icon:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  transition: 0.200s ease-out;
}
/*to make radio button clickable*/


.toggle-button--maa label {
  width: 110px; /*space between the options*/
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px; /*line spacing*/
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.toggle-button--maa label:before, .toggle-button--maa label:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 30px;
  width: 110px;
  transition: all 0.2s .1s ease-out;
}

.toggle-button--maa label:before {
  content: attr(data-text);
}

.toggle-button--maa input:checked ~ .toggle-button__icon:before {
  animation: wave .7s ease-out;
}

.toggle-button--maa input:checked ~ .toggle-button__icon:after {
  transform: scale(1);
  animation: zoomIn .2s;
}

.toggle-button--maa .toggle-button__icon {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.toggle-button--maa .toggle-button__icon:before, .toggle-button--maa .toggle-button__icon:after {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.toggle-button--maa .toggle-button__icon:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

.toggle-button--maa .toggle-button__icon:after {
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
  background: #61B136;
  animation: zoomOut .2s ease-out;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: none;
}

.toggle-button--maa:hover input:not(:checked) ~ .toggle-button__icon {
  animation: hover .2s;
}

.toggle-button--maa:hover input:not(:checked) ~ label:before {
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

@keyframes zoomOut {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }

  30% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }

  100% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
}

@keyframes zoomIn {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }

  90% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }

  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes hover {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }

  30% {
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }

  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes wave {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }

  40% {
    opacity: 0.2;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
}


@keyframes zoomFadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes zoomFadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(3);
  }

  90% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }

  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@keyframes hover {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }

  30% {
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }

  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
```

```html
<div id="ButtonsDiv" class="auto-style4" >
  <div class="toggle-button toggle-button--maa">
    <input id="toggleButton7" name="radio3" type="radio"/>
    <label for="toggleButton7" data-text="Bachelor accounting student" ></label>
    <div class="toggle-button__icon"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="toggle-button toggle-button--maa">
    <input id="toggleButton8" name="radio3" type="radio"/>
    <label for="toggleButton8" data-text="Bachelor finance student" class="auto-style5"></label>
    <div class="toggle-button__icon"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you set the `label` and the `:before` fixed width. Also, you set `position:absolute` to the `:before` element.

```css
html {
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
}

*, *::after, *::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Raleway', Arial, sans-serif;
}

.toggle-button {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  margin: 0 20px;
}
/*tested*/

.toggle-button label {
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: left;
}
/*tested*/

.toggle-button input {
  display: none;
}

.toggle-button__icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: none;
}
/*to let radio button invites clicking*/

.toggle-button__icon:before, .toggle-button__icon:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  transition: 0.200s ease-out;
}
/*to make radio button clickable*/


.toggle-button--maa label {
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px; /*line spacing*/
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.toggle-button--maa label:before, .toggle-button--maa label:after {
  margin-left:25px;
  transition: all 0.2s .1s ease-out;
}

.toggle-button--maa label:before {
  content: attr(data-text);
}

.toggle-button--maa input:checked ~ .toggle-button__icon:before,
.toggle-button--maa:hover input ~ .toggle-button__icon:before{
  animation: wave .7s ease-out;
}

.toggle-button--maa input:checked ~ .toggle-button__icon:after,
.toggle-button--maa:hover input ~ .toggle-button__icon:after {
  transform: scale(1);
  animation: zoomIn .2s;
}

.toggle-button--maa .toggle-button__icon {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.toggle-button--maa .toggle-button__icon:before, .toggle-button--maa .toggle-button__icon:after {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.toggle-button--maa .toggle-button__icon:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

.toggle-button--maa .toggle-button__icon:after {
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
  background: #61B136;
  animation: zoomOut .2s ease-out;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: none;
}

/*.toggle-button--maa:hover input:not(:checked) ~ .toggle-button__icon:after {
  background:#CACACA;
  transform: scale(1);
  animation: zoomIn .2s;
}*/

/*.toggle-button--maa:hover input:not(:checked) ~ .toggle-button__icon {
  animation: hover .2s;
}*/

.toggle-button--maa:hover input:not(:checked) ~ label:before {
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

@keyframes zoomOut {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }

  30% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }

  100% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
}

@keyframes zoomIn {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }

  90% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }

  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes hover {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }

  30% {
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }

  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes wave {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }

  40% {
    opacity: 0.2;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
}


@keyframes zoomFadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes zoomFadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(3);
  }

  90% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }

  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@keyframes hover {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }

  30% {
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }

  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
```

```html
<div id="ButtonsDiv" class="auto-style4" >
  <div class="toggle-button toggle-button--maa">
    <input id="toggleButton7" name="radio3" type="radio"/>
    <label for="toggleButton7" data-text="Bachelor accounting student" ></label>
    <div class="toggle-button__icon"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="toggle-button toggle-button--maa">
    <input id="toggleButton8" name="radio3" type="radio"/>
    <label for="toggleButton8" data-text="Bachelor finance student" class="auto-style5"></label>
    <div class="toggle-button__icon"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My pleasure ;) Good luck.

Comment: one more thing ,, as I said all of these codes copied from a website, I tried as much as I can to figure out what are the codes that are not necessary to delete it. and I have deleted some. But, I think that there are more codes which are unnecessary. what do you think ? I mean the CSS codes

Comment: You can delete it one by one, and check the effect. The fastest way is to create a [bin](http://jsbin.com) - this site has auto refresh option so you can comment a style and you can see the effect without refresh.

Comment: do you know how to show color when pointer comes over a radio button?     I have tried many codes and modified some but I didn't end up with a solution. Thanks!

Comment: I mean to let the button filled with color before clicking into it

Comment: I was updated my answer. I hope that this is what you are looking for.

Comment: YES this is what I wanted but I wanted it to be shown in the same style as before :s not filling the whole circle ,, sorry for all of this

Comment: How about now? Is this OK?

Comment: Can you create picture of the expected result?

Comment: http://codepen.io/ispal/pen/jWJabg 
look at the Valo one , I want the effect to be the same, 
in that case the effect happens only when the user click , but I want the same effect to happen even when the user only point on the radio button

Comment: the thing is that I want only the middle of the button to be filled , not the whole button , I want a grey borders with a green filling

Comment: So what will be the difference between the `:hover` and the `:checked` states?

Comment: I don't know :o, as I said I'm a beginner, 
To clarify again, the codes from the source I've given to you are good BUT it doesn't show the green color when the user just move the cursor over the radio button ( the green color effect apply only when the user click on the radio button )

Comment: Something like this?

Comment: Finally YES ! THANK YOU very much ! :DD

Comment: Done.. As your wish ;)